# When updating nuget package in VS2019, it appears as the latest version in the package references, but when inspecting it is still the old version

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I have created a local nuget package (as a local package source in a folder in the project).
When creating a new version and copy the .nupkg file to the folder, and going to the package manager, it does correctly show a new version is available from that local source.
I then update the package and it shows the latest version is installed in the package manager as well in the referenced packages in solution explorer and the csproj packagereferences.

But when i go to a class that implements an interface from that package, it still appears as the previous version of the package.
If I go to the definition of the interface it shows the previous version.

I tried several things, cleaning the package cache, deleting the .nuget/package folder, but without success.
The only way I can force to update to the latest package, is by deleting the bin and obj folders everytime I want to update the package.

Addition:
It is a Xamarin.Forms solution.
Apparently it is only in the Android project where the package appears as the old version. When deleting the bin folder from the Android project and rebuilding it, it can be forced to use the last package, but it has to be done every time you want to update the package.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved/worked around by installing the package in both cross-plaform and platform specific projects.